# How get email account settings from my Macbook Air onto my iPhone 5s?

Tags: iphone, email

I need to get the email account settings from my Macbook Air on to my iPhone 5s.

It was working perfectly until I got a new iPhone 5s. I backed everything up, but my email account for work is not working now, meaning I am out of the loop if I am not near my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

On your 5s, go to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars. Tap the email account, and make sure the Mail slider is on.

If the email account does not appear there, you have two options:

Add it using the email and password. More info can be found here:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201320
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201855

Or, provide additional info on the type of email account you're trying to use on both your Mac and iOS device for further troubleshooting, eg is it a POP, IMAP or Exchange account? If you are unsure, check it here:

https://ssl.apple.com/support/mail-settings-lookup/

Comment: thanks for your help. I thought my mac would hold the password for the account as I could not remember and it had not transferred with the rest of the data. I have resolved the issue with a keychain visual of my password on my mac. thanks Beatby